Number of cycles in $S_n$
Let $S_n$ denote the symmetric group on $n$ letters.
What is the number of all cycles (2-cycles, 3-cycles,..., $n$-cycles) in $S_n$?
By a simple discussion, we can see that it is equal to
$$\sum_{k=2}^n {n \choose k}(k-1)!=\sum_{k=2}^n {n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)\over k}.$$
Is there any formula for this number?

There is an explicit formula for the number of permutations of any given cycle type: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_type

@pancini Thanks for your comment. But the above number is the sum of numbers of all 2-cycles and the number of all 3-cycles and ... and the number of $n$-cycle. We have only one cycle in each permutation and I do not know how we can calculate this number using the formula for the number of permutation of a given type.

Maybe I don't understand the question. It seems like you included the desired formula in your post.

@pancini Somehow yes! Actually I try to find an exact formula which is the simplified form of the above equation.
